# DatePart returning 0

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following sql to convert hours to just minutes but it is returning 0. Why am I getting this ?

select (datepart(minute, '05:00:00.0000000'))

return 300

Comment: You probably want datediff instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the minutes section of 5am is 0 : ie 05:**00**:00

You want something like

```
select (datepart(minute, '05:00:00.0000000')) 
   + (datepart(hour, '05:00:00.0000000')*60)
```

or

```
select datediff(minute,  0, convert(time,'05:00:00.0000000'))
```

Comment: DATEDIFF returns the following error 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Thanks, perfect it is working. If I would like to take the amount and multiply it by money and return money type how would I do this ? Im getting a null returned by this syntax

Comment: SET @CalcTimeDelay = ((DATEDIFF(minute, 0, @PkgTimeDelay) - DATEDIFF(minute, 0,@CompanyTimeDelay))) * @ProdTimeDelayAmount;